# Can't seem to get correct permissions for mkdir() in PHP

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod, mkdir

I have the following simple script to test the mkdir() function in PHP:

```
<?php
  $id = rand();

  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sample_folder/' . $id .'/';
  mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);
?>
```

Ideally, this would create a random folder each time the script is run under my web directory/sample_folder. Sample_folder has 755 permissions.

The issue I face is, I keep running into PHP: mkdir() Permission denied issues. My sample_folder permissions are currently set to chmod 755.

**EVERYTHING** I have read states not to chmod to 777 so please don't suggest it.

For test purposes, chmod 777 the 'sample_folder' directory addresses the issue but again this poses security issues. Is there something else I am missing on how to make this work?

Of note: my PHP users on the system is "apache";

I am running PHP 5.3.* and CentOS 5.5 on a Media Temple dedicated virtual server for reference. I have also looked through nearly every chmod question on SO and cannot seem to find a solution that matches my issue (with the exception of 777 suggestions).

### edit

Running ls -la on my server returns:

> drwxr-xr-x    2   ftphiddenname   psacln    4096   Jan 26 11:24   sample_folder

### final update

The answers provided were very helpful. For anybody looking for additional information, I came across this knowledge base article and while it is listed on Media Temple, I blieve the principles apply to any most similar configurations:

[(dv):Resolve Apache permission errors](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29%3aResolve_Apache_permission_errors)

Comment: Rather than `chmod`ing, you need to [`chown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) to ensure that `755` is adequate for you to modify the directory in question. You would need `7` (`6`?) on the parent directory in order to do this - so if the parent directory is not owned by the user PHP is executing as, it won't let you do it with `755`.

Comment: @DaveRandom - thanks for the note. To be honest I'm fairly proficient with php but have some trouble getting around a linux server at times. Is there a specific command to find this information and address if it need be? My php user is 'apache' by the way.

Comment: If you `ls -l` in the parent directory's parent you can see the permissions and ownership on the parent (if you follow that, I would forgive you if you didn't). Essentially, in your example, you should `ls -l` the document root, you will see the info you want. Really all you need to do (as a user with permission to do it) is `chown apache <document root>/sample_folder`

Comment: @DaveRandom - thank you very much. The chown command on the folder did exactly what was needed. I will post a link to a specific KB article I just found but are there ways to prevent this in the future or always need to fix in one-off situations?

Comment: The folder will have been assigned the ownership of the user that created - looking at the output you've posted above, I'm guessing you created it via FTP, and every time you do this you will have this problem. To avoid it, you need to create the directories as the `apache` user (anything you create with PHP should do this), or `chown` them to `apache` when you create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the script needs write permissions in sample_folder.

I don't know your actual set up, but I'm guessing your script is either running under world permissions or group permission which is 5 (read 4 + execute 1) since your current permissions are 755 (7 for owner, 5 for group and 5 for world). To write directories into that folder, your script will need write access. You can set this up more securely than 777 if you have access to chown directories. My advice would be to create a group called 'webgroup' or similar and place your webserver user into that group. Then, give the group write permissions (770) would be appropriate once you have that set up. In case you're a little hazy on how the permissions work, the final setup would be:

sample_folder: owned by root, group webgroup, 770 permissions
add whatever user apache (or other webserver) is running as to webgroup

EDIT:

With more details available in the initial post, this means you would be adding the user 'apache' to webgroup. If you find this too difficult a setup or you do not have full permissions on the server to set this up then using chown as suggested elsewhere to let apache own the directory would work as well.

For example: chown apache sample_folder

This will make apache the owner of the folder, giving it access to write permissions (assuming it is still 755)

Comment: of note the sample_folder currently has 755 permissions.

Comment: Indeed, this is likely the reason why your script cannot write, it is probably operating with world permissions of 5, which only gives read and execute permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the filesystem permissions for the folder under which you are trying to create the directory?

You should `cd` into the directory and `ls -la` to see the current ownership and filesystem permissions:

```
paulbain@test ~/test $ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 paulbain apache 4096 Jan 26 17:38 .
```

In my example above, it's owner Read Write Execute, Group Read and Execute and Everyone Read and Execute.

If this was the case and you have your Apache running under a user in the group `apache`, PHP would not be able to create the directory.